# BasicObject を継承すると、自身のクラス名を解決できないのはなぜ？

Tags: ruby

通常のクラスでは、自身のクラス名は、問題なく解決できます。

```
class Hoge
  def new_my_class
    Hoge.new
  end
end

h = Hoge.new
p h.new_my_class
# => #<Hoge:0x000000032f6b58>
```

BasicObject を継承したクラスでは、これができないことがわかりました。

```
class HogeBasic < BasicObject
  def new_my_class
    HogeBasic.new
  end
end

h = HogeBasic.new
p  h.new_my_class
# # 以下の例外が発生する。
# NameError: uninitialized constant HogeBasic::HogeBasic
# Did you mean?  HogeBasic
```

これは、なぜなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

リファレンスマニュアルに次のようにあります。
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2fvariables.html#const

> クラス定義の外(トップレベル)で定義された定数は Object に所属することになります

なので Hoge も HogeBasic も Object に属する定数になります。

Hoge クラスは Object のサブクラスなので、Hoge の中で定数を参照すると Object に属する定数 Hoge も参照できますが、HogeBasic クラスは Object のサブクラスではないので、HogeBasic の中で定数を参照しても Object に属する定数 HogeBasic は参照できません。

なお `::HogeBasic` として参照することはできます。